# How can I return the last 5 rows from the updated table?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query where I want to update the last 5 rows only and get the values(more specifically the column city) updated

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | city        | is_active |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 1  | Los Angeles | false     |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 2  | London      | false     |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 3  | Barcelona   | false     |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 4  | Madrid      | false     |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 5  | Sydney      | false     |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 6  | Melbourne   | false     |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

I tried this:

```
WITH updated AS (UPDATE table_name SET is_active = true RETURNING city) SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE city IN (SELECT city FROM updated ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5);
```

This returns me the last rows exactly as I want but it updates ALL rows in true, what I'm missing on the UPDATE line? I would like to affect/update just the last 5 rows in true

```
+----+-------------+-----------+
| id | city        | is_active |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 2  | London      | true      |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 3  | Barcelona   | true      |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 4  | Madrid      | true      |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 5  | Sydney      | true      |
+----+-------------+-----------+
| 6  | Melbourne   | true      |
+----+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: `UPDATE table_name SET is_active = true WHERE id in (select id from table_name order by id DESC limit 5) RETURNING city`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Hey , thank you for your reply. Is possible to get the last rows affected? Doing that returns me just an int: Query executed successfully. Affected rows: 5.

Comment: The `RETURNING city` should return rows with the `city` name. A similar query on my end does. What client are you doing this in?

Comment: I'm using C# with NpgsqlConnection and Dapper

Comment: Then you will need to include the code you are using to run the query and fetch the results. As my answer below shows the `UPDATE` statement does what you want. Some part of your code is eating the return values.

Answer (score 1):

Using [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

```
CREATE TABLE city_test(id integer, city varchar, is_active boolean);

INSERT INTO
    city_test 
VALUES
    (1, 'Los Angeles', false),
    (2, 'London', false),
    (3, 'Barcelona', false),
    (4, 'Madrid', false),
    (5, 'Sydney', false),
    (6, 'Melbourne',false);

UPDATE 
    city_test 
SET 
    is_active = true 
WHERE 
    id IN 
        (SELECT id FROM city_test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) 
RETURNING city;

 city    
-----------
 London
 Barcelona
 Madrid
 Sydney
 Melbourne

SELECT * FROM city_test ;
 id |    city     | is_active 
----+-------------+-----------
  1 | Los Angeles | f
  2 | London      | t
  3 | Barcelona   | t
  4 | Madrid      | t
  5 | Sydney      | t
  6 | Melbourne   | t
```